# How to add the Tags column to a test suite query in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

I know how to add a column to a query but in TFS 2013 Web -> Test -> Test Suite I don't see an option to add Tags as a column. It is available from the regular Work -> Queries section though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test Suites, in the current version of TFS, are no work items. Tags are a work item feature and as such they're not available in this scenario.